# If $m(A^\circ)=m(\overline A)$ then $m(\overline A\setminus A^\circ)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $A^\circ$ and $\overline A$ denote the interior and the closure of $A$ respectively. Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$.

> Is it true that if $m(A^\circ)=m(\overline A)$ then $m(\overline A\setminus A^\circ)=0$?

I can show this easily if $m(\overline A)$ is finite: $m(\overline A)=m\Big((\overline A\setminus A^\circ)\cup A^\circ\Big)=m(\overline A\setminus A^\circ)+m(A^\circ)$. Now since $m(\overline A)$ is finite, I can subtract on both sides and I have the required result.

But what about when $m(\overline A)=\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then it is false. Take, say, $A=[0,\infty)\cup\bigl((-\infty,0)\cap\Bbb Q\bigr)$. Then $\overline A=\Bbb R$ and $\mathring A=(0,\infty)$. So,$$m\left(\overline A\setminus\mathring A\right)=m\bigl((-\infty,0]\bigr)=\infty.$$